# Django set GET parameter based on selection

Tags: python, django, http

in my html template, under `localhost:8000/`, I have some `hrefs`:

```
en en-us gb fr
```

When a users clicks `fr` I want to make the url to be `localhost:8000/country=fr`

How to do that? thanks

**views.py:**

```
langs = Language.objects.all()


    return render(request, 'themes_list.html', {'langs': langs})
```

**template:**

```
<h2>Select Language:</h2>
  {% for lang in langs %}
      <a href=".......">{{ lang.code }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: please post your current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a users clicks fr, you can make the url to

```
localhost:8000/?country=fr
```

by writing a html like

```
<a href="/?country={{lang.code}}">{{ lang.code }}</a>
```

The Url without question is not possible

> localhost:8000/country=fr

Comment: sure, with question mark. I was in a hurry. This wasn't my real question, I was a little dazzled, but I figure it out in the meantime. Thanks